# In ETCS, how do we take the limit of an infinite diagram?

Tags: foundations

As everyone knows, the category $\mathrm{Set}$ is complete, or in other words all small limits exist.

Now suppose we're using [ETCS](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS) as a foundation. I think we can take finite limits without issue. But, how do we define the limit of a diagram with (small but) infinite scheme? Indeed, how do we even define an infinite diagram?

I'm especially interested in the uncountable case.

Comment: This might be useful for you?http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Trimble+on+ETCS+III

Comment: @ZachL., thanks, but Trimble really only deals with finite operations in that post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're taking ETCS as a foundation, then *externally*, all you have to construct diagrams is what you can do in the language of first-order logic, and so the only (meta-)diagrams you can draw *are* finite, so there is no problem.

What you need is an *internal* notion of diagram, and then we can ask about taking limits and colimits of those.

The brief outline as I understand it is:

- Define internal categories. This is directly analogous to the usual definition of small category as a set of objects, a set of morphisms, et cetera. But since "set" now means "object of my topos" and so forth, this turns into the usual definition of internal category.
- For an internal category $J$, define internal functors $J \to \mathbf{Set}$. This is a trickier problem than defining a functor between two internal categories. The right approach is to use the equivalence between set-valued functors and category actions on a set. An internal functor is then defined to be an object of $\mathbf{Set}$ together with an action of $J$ on that object.
- Define the notions of limit and colimit for internal diagrams. This can be done externally by constructing the (meta)category $\mathbf{Set}^J$ of internal functors, and defining limits and colimits as the right and left adjoints to the diagonal $\mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{Set}^J$.

Comment: Thank you, this is a very detailed answer!